# angular material assets not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to make a fresh angular project with angular material. Installed everything with bower install, imported all the necessary files in my index.html. But styles aren't applied.

My index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="yathzee" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Yathzee app</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bower_components/angular-material/layouts/angular-material.layouts.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="assets/libs/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/libs/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard-environment-configuration.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/shared/menu.Controller.js"></script>

  <div ng-controller="menuController" ng-cloak="" class="navBardemoBasicUsage">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="vm.currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page1')" name="page1">Page One</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page2')" name="page2">Page Two</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-click="goto('page3')" name="page3">Page Three</md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>
    <main ng-view></main>
  </md-content></div>

</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var yathzee = angular.module('yathzee', ['ngMaterial','dashboard-environment-configuration', 'ngAnimate','ngAria']);


yathzee.config(['$mdThemingProvider',
    function($mdThemingProvider) {

        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('red')
            .accentPalette('amber');

    }
]);
```

Comment: Any `console` errors?

Comment: change `<script src="app.js">` to  `<script src="App.js">`.

Comment: @Chinni no there aren't any errors

Comment: @yash that doesn't work :(